# 'PointType’ is not a member of ‘Point’

Tags: c++

I am getting a compilation error saying " ‘PointType’ is not a member of ‘Point’ " I do not know what I need to implement in my code. Been thinking for a while now. I've tried adjusting the codes here and there a few times. But could not think of a solution for this. I'm a little confused by what "Point point(Point::PointType(x, y), depth);" in the main() wants. What exactly is PointType(x,y)? Can anyone enlighten me with what I should do? Would appreciate anyone's help on this. Side Note: Main() can't be touched. Thanks!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <cmath>

struct PointType
{
float x;
float y;
PointType(const float x1, const float y1) :x(x1),y(y1){}
};

class Object
{
private:
float d;
PointType * pt;
public:
Object(float n) : d(n){}

 float depth() const
{
    return d;
}
};

class Point :public Object
{
private:
PointType mpoint;

public:

Point(const PointType& pt, float& y1) : mpoint(pt), Object(y1) {}

virtual ~Point();

 };
```

Main file:

```
const float EPSILON = 1e-5f;

bool is_near(float x, float y)
{
return std::abs(x - y) < EPSILON;
}
float frand()
{
return 10.0f * float(rand()) / float(RAND_MAX);
}

int main()
{

srand(unsigned(time(0)));
int count = 0;
int max_count = 0;

float x = frand();
float y = frand();
float depth = frand();

Point point(Point::PointType(x, y), depth);
    if (is_near(point.depth(), depth))
{
    ++count;
}
else
{
    std::cout << "  - Point::depth test failed" << std::endl;
}
++max_count;


 }
```

Comment: If you remove `Point::` from `Point::PointType` in `main()` does it compile correctly?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention I can't change the main()

Comment: However, if I remove Point:: it does compile yes.

Comment: But by right I can't remove point::, coz whatever in my main is fixed alr. I just need to implement the codes according to my main().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got a set circular declarations that can't be resolved if you can't change `main()`. You currently have `PointType` as a `struct` outside of the `Point` class. That's fine, but then you need to change the line in `main()` from:

```
Point point(Point::PointType(x, y), depth);
```

to:

```
Point point(PointType(x, y), depth);
```

But if you can't do that, then you can't ever compile this because `Point` is a subclass of `Object`, but `Object` requires a `Point::PointType` which can't have been defined yet. In order to have `PointType` be owned by `Point`, you need to declare it like this:

```
class Point :public Object
{
    struct PointType
    {
        float x;
        float y;
        PointType(const float x1, const float y1) :x(x1),y(y1){}
    };
private:
    PointType mpoint;

public:

    Point(const PointType& pt, float& y1) : mpoint(pt), Object(y1) {}

    virtual ~Point();

 };
```

But once you put `PointType` into `Point`, you can't declare any member of `Object` to have a type of `Point::PointType` because `Point` inherits from `Object`.

You could declare `Object::pt` to be a `void*` but that throws away type information which is dangerous.